# How can I use sub attribute (or) nested attribute

Tags: php, magento, attributes, hierarchy, magento-1.4

I am building a site using Magento. I have to use nested / sub attributes. Is it possible in magento?

My requirement:
I have an attribute set as "Art Style”. Under this there are 4 attributes. 1. Fine Art, 2. Decorative art, 3. Vintage Art, 4. Photography. Again in Fine art I have these categories: a. Era, b. Movement, c. Nationality. How can I achieve this.I already have categories and subcategories (Abstract, Animals, Architecture etc.) for my products.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that Magento's native attribute model supports sub-attributes, however you could use Tags as they are non-hierarchical.  Not that I know much about art(!), but I would guess that some forms of art would cross the hierarchical boundaries anyway...

One downside is that they won't be filterable in the Layered Navigation, but you could potentially write an extension to include tags in the Layers.

You can manage the list of tags in Catalog>All Tags, and assign tags to individual products on the Edit Product screen under the Product Tags tab.